# Sending multiple messages from Client to Server

Tags: c++

My code between the client and server works as expected except for the connection closing prematurely after only one message has been sent or received. I want both the client and the server to stay open to send multiple messages without having to reinitialize the connection every time. My code is below:

Server

```
#undef UNICODE

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>


// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27016"

int __cdecl main(void)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;

    int iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(0, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);
    std::cout << "Server Starting..." << std::endl;
    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Setup the TCP listening socket
    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    iResult = listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN);
    std::cout << "Waiting for clients..." << std::endl;
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("listen failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Accept a client socket
    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("accept failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "In the server loop ready to receive a command..." << std::endl;

    // No longer need server socket
    //closesocket(ListenSocket);

    // Receive until the peer shuts down the connection
    do {

        iResult = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if (iResult > 0) {
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);

            std::cout << recvbuf << std::endl;

            // Echo the buffer back to the sender
            iSendResult = send(ClientSocket, recvbuf, iResult, 0);

            if (strcmp(recvbuf, "move") == 0) {
                std::cout << "Command received: " << recvbuf << std::endl;
            }
            else if (strcmp(recvbuf, "stats") == 0) {
                std::cout << "Command received: " << recvbuf << std::endl;
            }
            else if (strcmp(recvbuf, "shoot") == 0) {
                std::cout << "Command received: " << recvbuf << std::endl;
            }

            if (iSendResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
                printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
                closesocket(ClientSocket);
                WSACleanup();
                return 1;
            }
        }
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closing...\n");
        else {
            printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

    } while (iResult > 0);

    // shutdown the connection since we're done
    iResult = shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_SEND);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ClientSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ClientSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Client

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN

#include <windows.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using std::string;
using std::cin;

// Need to link with Ws2_32.lib, Mswsock.lib, and Advapi32.lib
#pragma comment (lib, "Ws2_32.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "Mswsock.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "AdvApi32.lib")


#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "27016"

int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL,
        *ptr = NULL,
        hints;

    // char *sendbuf = "this is a test";   //  disallowed with /permissive- flag
    //char *sendbuf = new char[strlen("this is a test")];

    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int iResult;
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;

    // Validate the parameters
    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("usage: %s server-name\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Initialize Winsock
    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

    // Resolve the server address and port
    iResult = getaddrinfo(argv[1], DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed with error: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    // Attempt to connect to an address until one succeeds
    for (ptr = result; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->ai_next) {

        // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
        ConnectSocket = socket(ptr->ai_family, ptr->ai_socktype,
            ptr->ai_protocol);
        if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
            printf("socket failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        // Connect to server.
        iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, ptr->ai_addr, (int)ptr->ai_addrlen);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    char *sendbuf = new char[DEFAULT_BUFLEN]();


        std::cout << "In the client ready to send a command..." << std::endl;


        cin.getline(sendbuf, DEFAULT_BUFLEN);

        int size;
        for (size = 0; sendbuf[size] != '\0'; size++);

        std::cout << sendbuf << std::endl;

        // Send an initial buffer
        iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, size, 0);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        printf("Bytes Sent: %ld\n", iResult);

        // shutdown the connection since no more data will be sent
        iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);
        if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
            printf("shutdown failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
        }

        std::cout << "Command sent: " << sendbuf << std::endl;

        // Receive until the peer closes the connection
        do {

            iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
            if (iResult > 0)
                printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
            else if (iResult == 0)
                printf("Connection closed\n");
            else
                printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            std::cout << iResult << std::endl;
        } while (iResult > 0);

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The client calls `send` once, then `shutdown`. If you want the connection to stay open, then, you know, don't close it.

Comment: When i comment the shutdown "iResult = shutdown(ConnectSocket, SD_SEND);" out it doesn't allow me to add any more input into command prompt. I have tried encasing it in a while loop that exits on the string "exit" and then shutsdown, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: The client only calls `getline` once, too. You can't add more input because the program doesn't read input anymore.

Comment: The server has a loop to read an inbound message and send an outbound message, on every loop iteration. The client needs a similar loop to read user input, send the input to the server, and read the server's reply, on every loop iteration. Right now your client is not looping the reading and sending of user input at all. It reads and sends user input only one time, then loops reading server replies. Move the reading and sending of user input into the loop. Once you fix that, your next task it to fix your actual sends and recvs, because you are not handling them correctly.

Comment: How are they not being handled correctly?